# is there any way to provide a digital signature with ngx-extended-pdf-viewer?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer #ngxExtendedPdfViewer [src]="selectedDocument.Url" height="80vh"
[language]="pdfLocal" [pageViewMode]="'single'">

Comment: Which kind of signature do you want to manage ? DocuSign signature ? where is the signing user private key certificate stored ? on a usb token ? in an ldap directory ? on a hardware security module ? providing a digital signature is not a viewer problem.

Comment: @Pierre actually i need to set the signature in any place of the pdf, i will send the signature to the backend as a base46

Comment: You might fork ngx-extended-pdf-viewer and inject a layer for the user to let him draw a rectangle where he wants the signature to be. I did this with konva ( https://konvajs.org/ ). Not with ngx-extended-pdf-viewer but directly with pdfjs in angular, to let users add annotations. It's a hard work, but it's doable :)

Answer (score 1):

Long story: I've documented the feature here: https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/signatures

Short story: like mentioned before, it's simply a matter of the attribute `[showUnverifiedSignatures]="true"`

Answer (score 0):

```
[showUnverifiedSignatures]="true"
```

Comment: Please consider adding some details around your answer.